# How can I turn my android phone into a remote control (mouse/keyboard) through bluetooth for ubuntu/linux

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control

There are a lot of apps that turn an android phone into a remote control for a desktop system, but only for windows based systems.

I use ubuntu and I only find Remote droid , works ok but only through a wifi network.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.joshsera&feature=search_result

I tried to used blueputdroid, and the app told me that didnot have support for my rom. My phone is a samsung galaxy S with android 2.1

https://market.android.com/search?q=blueputdroid&so=1&c=apps

Are there other apps that I do not know?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Check [**UnifiedRemote**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote) -- [site reference](http://www.unifiedremote.com/).
Requires Windows and .NET Framework 4.

---

Older reference,
Have you tried [URemoteDesktop](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.guatedroid.URemoteDesktop)?

> Designed to remote control any Ubuntu
>   desktop PC. (also can be used on
>   windows, but was designed for Ubuntu).
>   Change music (Previous, Next,
>   Play/Pause, Mute)
>   On Ubuntu any player
>   on system. (Totem, SongBird <<< no
>   need on focus the app).
>   On Windows
>   (Windows Media Player Presenter
>   functions (Next, previous) Compatible
>   with Power Point and OpenOffice.
>
> Screen Control / Desktop Control
>
> Remote WIFI Keyboard

Comment: Thanks its works, but I would like to have bluetooth support

Comment: Oops, I picked the wrong one then. Updated now.