# Control a PC with Air Gestures

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, remote-control

I'm aware of a few questions that talk about controlling a PC with an Android phone:

- [control android device from pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45289/control-android-device-from-pc)
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/is-there-an-android-application-for-remote-control
- [How to Remote Control Android smartphone, if not in same subnet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15695/how-to-remote-control-android-smartphone-if-not-in-same-subnet)
- [How can I turn my android phone into a remote control (mouse/keyboard) through bluetooth for ubuntu/linux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8410/how-can-i-turn-my-android-phone-into-a-remote-control-mouse-keyboard-through-b)

Is there any support for [**Air Gestures**](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000003/10141/120552) of the Galaxy S4 in any of these products? I would love to place my phone on table during a presentation and wave my hands around to magically advance the slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the **Air browse** feature under Air Gestures, you will see that it is limited only to the following applications:

- Gallery
- Internet
- Music Player
- Music on lock screen
- S Memo

So NO, you can't use it for presentations.

Comment: Does that preclude it from a developer writing an app for it? This morning I found a SO question asking the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649830/proximity-sensor-on-galaxy-s4-air-gestures

Comment: @Hooked If there's an API for it, it might be possible to create an app for it. [But I have no idea]

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Android Remote Computer Over android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.polytech.remotecomputer)  that can control your PC via your smartphone (mouse, keyboard) free and without ads .

Comment: The app description does nowhere state it supports "air gestures" (which is what the OP is after). Could you explain if it does so – and if not, how it answers the question?